# Should I put lock statements around C# Database Calls?

Tags: c#, locking

I am creating a class that is used as an portal to read, insert and update values within a SQL Server database.  This class implements the singleton design pattern, and therefore there will only be one instance of this class at any one time.

This class has individual methods for each action for the database values  (read, write & delete), and each of those methods will open a SQLConnection, create, populate & execute the SQLCommand, and finally close the connection once completed.

Here is the example for adding a value:

```
public void AddGlossaryValue(string name, string value)
{
   SqlConnection connection = null;
   SqlCommand command = null;

   try
   {
      connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
      connection.Open();

      command = new SqlCommand(SQL_INSERT_COMMAND, connection);
      command.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
      command.Parameters.Add("@value", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);

      command.Parameters["@name"].Value = name;
      command.Parameters["@value"].Value = value;

      command.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      // handle exception - omitted in this example because it's irrelevant
   }
   finally
   {
      try
      {
         connection.Close();
      }
      catch (Exception) { }
   }
}
```

I come from a Java background, where typically you would declare such methods as Synchronized, which means that the method can only be executed from one source at any one time.  From my research into C#, it would appear that the typical method for achieving this is to lock and object.

My question is however, would that be recommended in a case such as above, and if so, where would the lock object be placed?  Would it be immediately before the creation of the SQLConnection?

Many thanks

Comment: A word of advice: instead of try/finally, you could just put your database connection in a `using` block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why lock at all?  You're not using any shared resources in your dll code.

Just catch the sql error you'd likely see from a collision.  If you insert something that's already there, then you can do whatever happens to be appropriate at the time.

Save locking for shared resources in the code; things multiple threads could be accessing where you need to ensure determinant behavior.  This code looks like you're just firing something off to the database, you won't be getting any behavior that you couldn't easily explain by not using locks here.

Comment: +1 for common sense that ain't so common. So many people just throw locks around (or mark methods synchronized in java) without having even the slightest clue why; just a vague notion of "thread safety."

Answer (score 1):

I'm not at all a fan of using a Singleton for this purpose.  Using individual instances would make a major leap forward for thread safety.  No lock necessary.

Comment: A singleton is necessary in this case because it caches the list of key/value pairs.  The purpose is to prevent the number of database reads required for the application.  Therefore if 10 people are using the corresponding ASP.Net pages, they would all be sharing from the same resource pool of key/value pairs.

Comment: Not to mention testability, since you can't mock a static class.

Comment: @DBM: I have no trouble mocking them.

Answer (score 1):

That piece of code doesn't need locks, since you're not accessing any shared state. But your comment about "caching list of key/value pairs" would certainly need it around reading/writing the list.

Comment: Good point regarding reading/writing the list.  I overlooked that.

Answer (score 0):

While I can imagine a few cases where this would be really useful (e.g. you're using SQLite), in most cases it is a bad idea to do the locking yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can Definetly use the `lock(){//code block}` statement, it will make sure that the Thread execution does not enter a critical state.

But, as good as i know, if you use different SqlConnections for each command then it automatically becomes thread safe.

Also, you can use SqlTransaction class.

```
SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
    SqlTransaction transaction;       
    transaction = connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);       
    command.Connection = connection;
    command.Transaction = transaction;
```

Just to have that extra bit of control over your application.